# Oracle Service bus 11g- Scenerio

Tags: osb

For OSB 11G,I have to manage 2 endpoints(let it be URL1 and URL2)  to support 24x7 availability(where URL1 works from 8.00 hrs  till 20.00 hrs and URL2 works from 20.00 hrs to 8.00hrs).

I have handled this in business service under transport configuration :

1) create 2 endpoints  (URL1 and URL2)

2) set retry count to 1

This worked okay but when switch  happens from URL1 to URL2  and vice versa OSB-client(s) experiences delay, is there any way by which we can make URL1 offline from 20.00 hrs to 8.00 hrs and OSB do not try to attempt to hit URL1 for that duration?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: there is no code in OSB which I can write, its all configuration on weblogic OSB console. I wrote clearly what I did (in 2 steps)and what I want to do

Comment: If there's no code, then it's obviously not a programming problem, and it can't be on topic for [so].  If it's a system configuration issue, then [sf] is a more likely place to find help.

Comment: @HiteshRamnani what did you set your `Retry Iteration Interval` to?

Comment: FYI - you can still share the raw XML from your OSB artifacts (.bix / business service in this case)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to mark the inactive URI "offline" - as with your current setup, you rely on the retry count which makes the OSB first access the inactive endpoint and then fail over to the active one. 
See: 
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/osb/administer/GUID-C49400DC-26DD-4175-972A-19DCAE5BCDD0.htm#OSBAG605

You might be able to find a way to do this using a WLST script and schedule it to run at appropriate times automatically